# How to Reload JSONObject Content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

The code below generates json data dynamically from the database. When the data is generated it adds it to a specific div. How can i make the contents of JSONObject reload every 30 seconds. This will make it so that content shows changes in near real-time.

```
<script>

JSONObject = <?php echo include_once('../includes/dashboard-stats.php'); ?>;

document.getElementById("today_visits").innerHTML=JSONObject.todayVisits;

</script>
```

Below is the output of `JSONObject = <?php echo include_once('../includes/dashboard-stats.php'); ?>;`

```
JSONObject = {"todayEarnings":"2.60","todayVisits":"212","todayClicks":"36","todayLeads":"3","todayCalculateCR":"12%","todayEPC":"0.08","todayCTR":"17%","yesterdayEarnings":"0.40","yesterdayClicks":"35","yesterdayVisits":"148","yesterdayLeads":"1","yesterdayCalculateCR":"35%","yesterdayEPC":"0.03","yesterdayCTR":"24%","monthEarnings":"3.00","monthClicks":"75","monthVisits":"392","monthLeads":"4","monthCalculateCR":"19%","monthEPC":"0.05","monthCTR":"19%"}

    1;
```

I tried using this to try and reload the json data.

```
<script>
 function load(){
JSONObject = <?php echo include_once('../includes/dashboard-stats.php'); ?>
document.getElementById("today_visits").innerHTML=JSONObject.todayVisits;
 setTimeout("load()",9000);
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Your last code looks code, only you need to make a proper ajax call without any PHP stuff

Comment: Why did you tag this with `jquery`? If you use jquery, check out its ajax functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED THE ANSWER:**

```
<script>      
   function load() {
        var colors = ["#CCCCCC","#333333","#990099"]; 
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length); 

        $.getJSON("../includes/dashboard-stats.php", { get:"stats" },function(data) {
             $("#today_visits").fadeOut().fadeIn().html(data.todayVisits).css("background-color", colors[rand]);
        });
    }
    $(function() {
        load();//on the page load.
        setInterval(load,9000);
    });
</script>
```

the url to ../includes/dashboard-stats.php is relative to the location of the page on which the script it present

Comment: Won't work because the PHP gets executed once and so it will get "updated" every x seconds with the same content

Comment: +1 Although personally I would set a timeout in the callback function instead of using an interval. Just to be safe.

Comment: How can i add a fadein effect and also different background color when it changes?

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP code Runs only One type Thats Why Result show Same.
Use Ajax Call and Get New Data from DB through PHP FILE every 30 Second.

//Jquery Syntax

```
$.post("Your PHP SCRIPT FILE PATH HERE", { PARAMS you want to pass }, function( Get DATA FROM PHP FILE ) {

// HERE IS YOU Operation

},"DATA FORMAT");
```

==================================

//CODE Example

```
function loadStats(){
 $.post( "../includes/dashboard-stats.php", { get:"stats" }, function(data) {
    $("#today_visits").html(data.todayVisits);
 }, "json");
}
$(function(){
     loadStats();
    setInterval(loadStats,9000);
}):
```

Comment: How can i prevent that 9sec delay before data shows for first time. On page load its blank for 9 secs before i see the data

Answer (score 0):

With the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/), we can do something like;

```
setInterval(load, 5000);

function load() {
  $.get('../includes/dashboard-stats.php', function(ReturnData) {
    JSONObject = ReturnData
  });
}
```

- Create a loop with `setInterval`
- Within the function `load`, create an ajax request to get the data.

`ReturnData` holds the output (HTML) of what is generated when `../includes/dashboard-stats.php` is triggered - try run it in your browser, and then find where the data is you're wanting to use.

#### Edits

- Removed `"load()"` from line 1 after [Moonwave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1073758/moonwave99) comment

Comment: Should be `setInterval(load, 5000);`, w/o braces.

Comment: I added this to my site and i see no data